# iOS: Navigation bar with images for buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I would like to create a NavigationBar with images as buttons on the right side of the NavigationBar.

Something like below Snapshot

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hope This Helps

```
viewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. How can I handle touches on this button?

Comment: Nice!! I tried both this and below Kamarshad answer but this answer is much better as the Button Icon looks nice with "initWithCustomView"

Answer (score 8):

Here the Code, Just call below Methods From `viewDidLoad`  method

```
  - (void)addCustomButtonOnNavBar
  {
   UIBarButtonItem * item1= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"passImageNmae1"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction1)];
   UIBarButtonItem * item2= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"passImageNmae2"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction2)];
  NSArray * buttonArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1,item2 ,nil];

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =buttonArray;

  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It tries to put the image ON a button. I want the image to be the button itself.

Comment: In other words I could not achieve the screenshot I posted using this code.

Comment: @Karamshad Button is very big. How to set proper size fit to navigation bar?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *viewWithButtons = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
//view customization
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//Button customiztaion
[viewWithButtons addSubview:leftButton];
UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//Button customiztaion
[viewWithButtons addSubview:rightButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:viewWithButtons];
[viewWithButtons release];
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a category for this:

UIBarButtonItem+WithImageOnly.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIBarButtonItem (WithImageOnly)

- (id)initWithImageOnly:(UIImage*)image target:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end
```

UIBarButtonItem+WithImageOnly.m:

```
#import "UIBarButtonItem+WithImageOnly.h"

@implementation UIBarButtonItem (WithImageOnly)

- (id)initWithImageOnly:(UIImage *)image target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {    
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    frame = CGRectInset(frame, -5, 0);

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return [self initWithCustomView:button];
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImageOnly:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] target:self action:@selector(someAction:)]
```