# UIBarButtonItem - changing background and removing text

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to change the **Done** button in `presentViewController` in Navbar where I succesfully was able to change the background using this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Now, when changing the Done button replacing it with an image, the image is repeating and the Done text stays there. Using this:

```
UIImage *doneBackgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-home.png"]
                                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

            [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:doneBackgroundImage
                                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here please?

Answer (score 0):

**STEP : 1**

Create a UIButton and assign it to UIBarButtomItem using `initWithCustomView` in your presentViewContoller

```
UIImage *customImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourCustomImage"];
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, customImage.size.width, customImage.size.height);
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourCustomImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPreviousView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

**STEP  :2**

You can find more from this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122817/ios-navigation-bar-with-images-for-buttons)

```
 viewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
    UIBarButtonItem * item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage2.jpg"]]];    
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

Comment: sorry, but none of the solutions worked for me. I'm on iOS8. I just need to simply remove the DONE text from the navbar when previewing the PDF files and replace it with Home image.

Comment: OK, I was able to clear the DONE text using: `NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [UIColor clearColor],
                                        UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                        [UIColor clearColor],
                                        UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];
            
            [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: attributes
                                                        forState: UIControlStateNormal];` but how do I don't repeat the image