# Show Current Location's Weather

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, weather

I have Seen this beautiful, intuitive & simple way to show my current location's Weather in an app :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YShN.jpg)

and i wanted to know how can i do it myself on the `NavigationBar`.
i looked for a tutorial like this but never found one so i would really appreciate any guide , Tutorial or a `Code` that will help me implement Current Location Weather displayed like this in my project as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid tutorial/library/add requests aren't on topic on Stack Overflow. I'd start by Googling something like `ios add icon to navigationbar` which seems to yield very useful results

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122817/ios-navigation-bar-with-images-for-buttons (but that's for Obj-C)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022780/uibarbuttonitem-in-navigation-bar-programmatically (should be the right thing, if I'm not mistaken, and for Swift)

Comment: Haha that's one thing , Thanks. But im really more intereseted about the weather mechanism & how it works . @Pekka웃

Comment: That's far too big to ask in a Stack Overflow question here, too - SO is generally for very specific technical questions with a correct answer. There's tutorials out there though, see e.g. http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/04/02/how-to-build-an-ios-weather-app-in-swift-part-1-a-very-bare-bones-weather-app/ Here's a code sample for how to get data from OpenWeatherMaps: https://github.com/filippotosetto/SwiftOpenWeatherMapAPI

Comment: Sadly i saw this one and as everyone in the comments below its not working . I really looked hard and couldn't find anything close to my example app approach . That's why i came here @Pekka웃

Comment: It's really too complex for Stack Overflow - you could write a tutorial or a book to answer this question well. What you want to learn is to talk to remote APIs using Swift. That's what a weather app essentially is about. I'd look in that direction. Udemy.com has a couple of video courses that deal with this as part of their generic "Learn Swift" type courses.

Comment: https://maniacdev.com/2013/12/example-a-beautiful-open-source-ios-weather-app

Comment: It's in Obj-C :'( and i barely started a couple of weeks ago to learn swift xD . Anyway i understand its probably too complicated for me.Although i really liked that feature.

Comment: Indeed. Yeah, there's way more Obj-C tutorials out there than Swift ones. It *is* a bit of a big project for a totally new user - incidentally, I am building a specialized weather app myself for my region in my free time. I have 15 years experience parsing APIs, building web apps and such, but it's still a lot of work even for me. But don't despair, you'll get there :) And as said, if you're into video courses, take a look at Udemy.

Comment: Woah ! :) Thanks and Good luck with your app :)